# In ipython notebook, how to clear all the variable after execution?

Tags: python, ipython

In the ipython notebook, in one cell, I read a very large data file and created many large lists from that file. After execution, I want to free the memory of all the variables in this cell. Because if I don't do that, in the next cell, I can still refer to these created variables. i.e they are in the memory, so the computer memory easily get to its limit. How to achieve this?

In mathematica, one can just use ``` Clear["Global``*"] ``` to achieve this. I don't know how to achieve this in ipython notebook

Comment: just like in regular python. Call `del <variable-name>` to indicate that <variable-name> can be freed.

Comment: Have a look also at the `%reset` and `%reset_selective` magics.